# Rational Polynomials that evaluate to integers when n! is plugged in, for any natural number n

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, integer-valued-polynomials

I was reading about integer-valued-polynomials -- rational single-variable polynomials that evaluate to integers when integers are plugged in for the variable. I read that all binomial polynomials $\binom{x}{n}$ = $\frac{x (x-1) \cdots (x-n+1)}{n!}$ are integer valued polynomials.

Similarly, I wanted to see (even examples would suffice) that evaluate to integers when n! is plugged in (for an natural 'n') but wouldn't evaluate to integers for all integers 'n'. A concrete example apart from above mentioned binomial polynomials or any source that talks about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example is
$$f(x)=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)}{5}.$$
For $n\in\Bbb Z$, $f(n)$ is an integer iff $n\not\equiv 3\pmod 5$, and there is
no factorial $\equiv3\pmod 5$.

Comment: Following through your idea I found some more examples. Is there any resource that points towards a general formula for these polynomials or describe these polynomials? Since they form a ring, what about their ideals?

Comment: There is some literature on polynomials that take all integers to integers, but I'm not aware of any on the polynomials that map factorials to integers ... maybe something worth investigating.